# Breaking Dijkstra algorithm when reaching my target in C

Tags: loops, break, dijkstra, infinite

I have implemented the dijkstra algorithm, to work with the two dimensional array. Everything runs just fine, but it is not very efficient, because when my **map is defined as map[10000][20000], and let's say I run dijkstra from starting position of [0][0], and I want to know the shortest path to a vertex with coordinates of [15][7], it is pointless to calculate thousands of unnecessary vertexes, if I need just that specific one.

For that case, I call my Dijkstra function with the parameters of type POINT (which hold my coordinates), but I am unable to break the loop, when the shortest path to my target is calculated.

This is my Dijkstra algo:

```
BLOCK *dijkstra(char **map, int height, int width, POINT start, POINT target) {
int position, i, speed, temp_distance;
BLOCK *blocks;          // all blocks in **mapp graph 
BLOCK block;            // current block
POINT temp;             // POINT is a variable from BLOCK structure, it contains coordinates
POINT *neighbours;      // array of POINT structures, holding coordinates of each neighbour for a specific block

// initializing every block in the **map (visited 0, distance INT_MAX, predecessor UNSET, etc.)
blocks = init(map, height, width);

// setting the starting position for dijkstra
position = start.y * width + start.x;
blocks[position].distance = 0;               // distance to itself is zero

push(blocks[position]);
block = pop();

while (block.distance != UNSET) {
    count = 0;
    block.visited = 1;
    temp.x = block.this.x;
    temp.y = block.this.y;
    neighbours = get_neighbours(map, height, width, temp, &count);

    // for loop for each neighbour of the current block
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        speed = get_speed(map, neighbours[i].y, neighbours[i].x);   // number of time-units to move through this block
        temp_distance = block.distance + speed;                     // total time (so far)
        position = neighbours[i].y * width + neighbours[i].x;       // position to current neighbour

        // if the distance is not set yet, or I just found a faster path
        if (blocks[position].distance < 0 || temp_distance < blocks[position].distance) {
            blocks[position].distance = temp_distance;              // overwriting distance to this block
            blocks[position].prev = block.this;                     // setting predecessor

            // this is my first time visiting this block
            if (blocks[position].visited == 0) {
                push(blocks[position]);
                blocks[position].visited = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    block = pop();
}
return blocks;
```

I thought I could achieve this by breaking the loop, if the coordinates of the current block (vertex) are the same, as the coordenates of my target AND the for loop for each neighbour of the current vertex was completed. To do this, I added this line:

```
if(block.this.x == target.x && block.this.y == target.y) break;
```

Right after the for loop. But the program seems to be stuck at an infinite loop in different function in this part:

```
blocks = dijkstra(map, height, width, start, target);       
position = target.y*width + target.x;

while ((blocks[position].this.x != start.x) || (blocks[position].this.y != start.y)) {
    //do stuff
    //...
    //set position to the predecessor of the current block
    position = blocks[position].prev.y*width + nodes[position].prev.x;
}
```

The loop never reaches the starting point. The weird part is, I run this block of code four times (just with different start and target vertexes), because I want to get the distance of:

[0][0] -> vertex A -> vertex B -> **vertex C -> vertex D**

and it only gets to an infinite loop in this case (bold - C is start, D is target)), while there are literally no differences except for start and target.

Thank you very much for your help!